# Why do I have the eclipse error, is this code valid or it is an eclipse bug?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

here the code from https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/tree/master/src

when viewing this from eclipse for php (latest, Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0))
the line 
 int $error = \UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
is highlighted as error with message "Constant expression contains invalid operations"
When removing "\" from "\UPLOAD_ERR_OK" error disapperars but its not a solution. 
Who is wrong? What does happen?

```
<?php

namespace Psr\Http\Message;

interface UploadedFileFactoryInterface
{
/**
* Create a new uploaded file.
*
 * If a size is not provided it will be determined by checking the size of
 * the file.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.post-method.php
 * @see http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php
 *
 * @param StreamInterface $stream Underlying stream representing the
 *     uploaded file content.
 * @param int $size in bytes
 * @param int $error PHP file upload error
 * @param string $clientFilename Filename as provided by the client, if any.
 * @param string $clientMediaType Media type as provided by the client, if any.
 *
 * @return UploadedFileInterface
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the file resource is not readable.
 */
public function createUploadedFile(
    StreamInterface $stream,
    int $size = null,
    int $error = \UPLOAD_ERR_OK, // <== ERROR IS HERE
    string $clientFilename = null,
    string $clientMediaType = null
): UploadedFileInterface;
}
```

Comment: why prefix the constant with a leading backslash??

Comment: This is valid, and I highly doubt this (using it for constants) was introduced after return value types were.

Comment: @RamRaider Since this code is within a namespace, not prefixing with a backslash would look up the constant in that namespace, as opposed to the root (default) one.

Comment: because that constant is from root namespace. not from Psr\Http\Message namespace.

Comment: See https://github.com/php-fig/http-factory/issues/3

Comment: @jeto - thanks for that, should have spotted that myself.